# Query to calculate the general average of a student

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Here are the tables from which I want to calculate the general average of a student:

- student (stdId, stdName)
- Course (courseId, name, coefficient)
- Score (stdId, courseId, score)

I want to use this formula:

```
((score1 * coefficient) + (score2 * coefficient) + (scoreN * coefficient)) / sum of coefficients
```

Example:

```
((14 * 3) + (15 * 2) + (18 * 4)) / 9
```

which will result in: 16

**Note:** [14, 15, 18] are the scores and [3, 2, 4] are the coefficients of each score and 9 is the sum of the coefficients.

Comment: So... What's wrong with the expression in SQL? T-SQL does maths just like any other  language. Though, for your example, the expression `((143)+(152)+(18*4))/9` doesn't result in 16, it's 40: `((143)+(152)+(18*4))/9 = (143+152+72)/9 = 367 / 9 = 40`

Comment: @Larnu the multiplication operator was hidden i have just edited it

Comment: Please, share the code you have so far and describe what is wrong with it. To check its correctness it is also required to add sample data in text format or as `insert` statements and desired output for that source data.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to join all the tables, then `group by s.stdid` and get `sum(s.score * c.coefficient) / sum(c.coefficient)` Does that not work?

Comment: Please show an actual [mre] with sample data in a temp table, your actual query, the results it produces and the results you want to see.

Comment: @Larnu SQL Server doesn't do "maths" like any other language. In many languages both of the following expressions have numeric results: `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / -3 / 5;`. SQL Server blesses one of them with a divide-by-zero.

Comment: @Charlieface yeah it is correct as Gordon Linoff wrote, though thank you as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You seem to be describing aggregation after joining tables together:

```
select s.stdid,
       sum(s.core * c.coefficient) / sum(c.coefficient)
from course c join
     score s
     on c.courseid = s.courseid
group by s.stdid
```